# inline script is showing on other page where it is not implemented in nextjs

Tags: next.js

I have placed an inline script from third party in a certain page in nextjs head tag. In the respective page inline script dynamically places the output. I don't have to place any other tag except their inline tag.
But when I navigate to my home page using my buttons, the output of that inline script still shows in the site.After reloading the script does not give any output. How do I stop loading this script on the pages where it is not defined in header tag?

Default inline script code:

```
function init_my_page(){
              // Add our cplus javascript to your document header
              var cplus_js = document.createElement("script");
              
              cplus_js.src = "src_file";
              cplus_js.onload = load_cplus;
              document.head.appendChild(cplus_js);
                           
              }
              
              function load_cplus(){
              // Dynamically place container div in the required position on your page
              var tl_cplus = document.createElement("div");
              
              tl_cplus.setAttribute("id","value");
              ${
                data
                  ? `tl_cplus.setAttribute("key",${data.record_id});`
                  : ""
              }
              tl_cplus.setAttribute("key","value");
              document.body.appendChild(tl_cplus);
              
              
              // Initiate the service with our javascript load function
              load_content_plus();
              }
              
              // Run your own javascript after the page has loaded
              if (window.addEventListener){
              window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init_my_page, false);
              }
              else if (window.attachEvent){
              window.attachEvent("onload", init_my_page);
              };
```

for testing purpose, I created an div with id="content-plus" and then placed their output in my div. so that in other pages the script won't find my created div with id="content-plus"

my edited script code:

```
 /function load_cplus(){
              // Dynamically place container div in the required position on your page
              var tl_cplus = document.createElement("div");
              var mydiv = document.findElementById("content-plus");
              tl_cplus.setAttribute("id","tl_cplus");
              ${
                data
                  ? `tl_cplus.setAttribute("key",${data.record_id});`
                  : ""
              }
              tl_cplus.setAttribute("key","value");
              mydiv.appendChild(tl_cplus);
              
              
              // Initiate the service with our javascript load function
              load_content_plus();
              }
```

in my component page:

```
<div id="content-plus"></div>
```

But now my inline-script is not working as expected. sometimes it shows and sometimes it does not. Can anyone help?

Comment: For people who are also looking for the answer to this question, I solved this modifying my router events implemented in useEffect function in _app.js file.

`useeffect(()=>{

return ()=>{
router.events.off("routeChangeComplete",()=>{
if(router.asPath.indexOf("xlmedia") == -1){
const ds = document.getElementById("tl_cplus");
if(ds){
ds.remove()
}
}
})
}
},[router.asPath])

`

Comment: Please add the solution that worked for you as an answer to your own question.